# How should I write about done tasks?

Tags: past-simple, time

When I finish my work, I need to write a simple report about completed tasks. What time should I use?

Now my report usually looks like:

```
Fix bag with this
Update that
Clean up
```

Should I use past simple to write about tasks that I've done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a to-do list or a task list, it is normal to use a [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) style: generally you use present tense, even if the events occurred in the past:

> Unorthodox candidate runs for prez
>   Trump triumphs
>   Key states fuel victory

If you wanted to write a formal report about what you had achieved during the day, past simple would be appropriate, but you would have to write in complete, grammatical sentences:

> Today, I fixed damaged bag with gaffer tape, updated the delivery schedule for spare parts and  cleaned up the office.